# jquery autocomplete with multiple sources

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a web form with radio buttons and a input field for autocomplete. Based on the selected radio button a different webservice (url) needs to be called to work with the data that the user is entering in input field.
The following code works well, but I don't know how to make it more flexible to accept different URL's.

```
        $("#txtCriteria").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            delay: 500,
            url: "../../CommonWebServices/wsEntity.asmx/ReportBuildings",
            data: "{ 'Name': '" + request.term + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Text,
                        value: item.Value
                    }   // end of return
                })) // end of response
            }   // end of success
        });     // end of ajax
    },  // end of source
    minLength: 1,
});
```

Here are the radio buttons. So If I select Region the webservice URL is different then the Building.

```
                        <input id="Radio1" type="radio" value="S" name="rblRptChoice" class="label" checked="checked" />State Wide<br />
                <input id="Radio2" type="radio" value="P" name="rblRptChoice" class="label" />Prosperity Region<br />
                <input id="Radio3" type="radio" value="R" name="rblRptChoice" class="label" />Region<br />
                <input id="Radio4" type="radio" value="T" name="rblRptChoice" class="label" />Cluster<br />
                <input id="Radio5" type="radio" value="C" name="rblRptChoice" class="label" />CEPD<br />
                <input id="Radio6" type="radio" value="F" name="rblRptChoice" class="label" />Fiscal Agency<br />
                <input id="Radio7" type="radio" value="B" name="rblRptChoice" class="label" />Building<br />
                <input id="Radio8" type="radio" value="P" name="rblRptChoice" class="label" />CIP Code<br />
                <input id="Radio9" type="radio" value="Y" name="rblRptChoice" class="label" />Year<br /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblDetails" runat="server" Text="Enter Details"></asp:Label><br />
                <input id="txtCriteria" type="text" placeholder="Enter Criteria" style="width:250px" />
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: The `source` function is invoked every time the autocomplete searches for a new term. Nothing prevents you from making the `url:` value in the ajax call depend on whatever radio input is currently selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the path value in a variable when the radio button is selected and then set the url to the variable.